# WebClient not supported

Tags: blazor

Trying to use `WebClient` in Blazor project.

Getting following error:

In `blazor.webassembly.js:1`

```
WASM: System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
```

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
```

How to make an API/Network call in Blazor?

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you trying to use `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient`?

Comment: I'm not. This is a question asked in github, and I thought it'd be better if I answer it here, so other people may learn from it. Issues in github have short life span: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10408

Comment: That's fine, but if you're going to self-answer a question to which you already know the answer, it's a bit more courteous to include the answer with your question at time of posting.  ("Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WebClient is not supported on Blazor. You should use HttpClient instead. In Blazor client side HttpClient is provided by the framework as a service; thus, you can inject it into your components or normal classes. In server-side Blazor this offer is missing, and you should create and configure the HttpClient yourself. You can also use IHttpClientFactory to provide HttpClient, which is preferable.

Note: WebClient cannot be used on the Browser (client-side Blazor) simply because it is relatively old technology, and there is no reason to adapt it to use on the browser. You probably believed that it is possible because HttpClient can run on the browser, but it may be a good idea to clarify here that when you use HttpClient on the browser, you don't actually use the actual HttpClient, which may use websockets, etc, but an adaptation form of HttpClient, which behind the scene use the JavaScript Fetch API.

Hope this helps...

Good news:

> Moving to the mono.wasm bindings should enable support for WebSockets,
>   HttpClient without addition code on our side, etc.

Source: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10489